# PowerPoint presentation saved as PPSX

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have saved a powerpoint presentation which i choose to have certain rules as PPSX. 
I have made a menu in the first pptx, formed of shapes that navigate to certain slides and back to the home menu. Then I disabled the access to other sites in the PPT (the user of the ppt can only navigate through the shapes in the menu). Then i have saved the pptx as ppsx and it works as intended. The user can see only the slides allowed by the menu and not all the slides that exist in the PPT.

The problem is this: when saved as ppsx and the ppsx and then opened via mobile (ios or android), the rules that i established do not apply (the ppsx is not locked to only menu slide). I also mention that i set the powerpoint in the slideshow setup (i set to not be able to use arrow keys or mouse click to navigate).

How can i fix this, to have the same options from pc also for mobile?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to circumvent the slide show navigation features on iOS using the **General** | **Accessibility** | **Guided Access** and had some success by disabling specific screen areas but I think the problem you face i.e. that a ppsx file does not automatically open in slide show mode unless on a PC/Mac is the root cause and unsolvable because that's down to Microsoft to address in their products.

Comment: Jamie's correct. If it's important for the iOS/web versions to treat PPSX files the same way MacOS/Windows versions of PPT do, please visit powerpoint.uservoice.com, choose the version you want to request the feature for and explain the request. The PPT dev team watches uservoice closely.

Comment: This is sad for me. Pff so practically i can't use this option for what i have in mind. Thank you very much for making time and answering me!!!